What does "There goes the neighborhood" mean here?
In Vice (2018), the news about President Ford losing the election is currently being
broadcast on TV:

Newsreader: Dick Cheney, the president's Chief of Staff, he does not
have a job. At one point, he was a broker.

Dick Cheney’s wife, Lynne, watches the news and reacts to it:

Dick Cheney's wife Lynne: It can't be. It's got to be some sort of a
mistake. A miscalculation.
Donald Rumsfled: There goes the neighborhood.

I understand that this phrase is often used to express disapproval or concern
about changes in one’s community or environment. However, I’m not entirely sure
about its usage in this particular context.
What does "There goes the neighborhood" mean here?

My best guess: Rumsfeld supported Ford's campaign, and believes that the lost election will have an adverse effect on society. His there goes the neighbourhood statement is his somewhat proverbial way of saying that.

"There goes the neighborhood" began as a racist exclamation in the US. It was used during the 1950s and 1960s to lament the anticipated decline in property values when a black family moved into a formerly all-white neighborhood. It could be paraphrased as "Say goodbye to the neighborhood".  It's said by a Republcan in response to the Republicans losing that election.
